# CordovaInAppBrowser exit event not working in ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework

I am developing hybrid mobile app in ionic framework. I am try to call CordovaInAppBrowser plugin but CordovaInAppBrowser exit event doesn't work for me

my code is given below  please help me.

```
var finalurl="url of my server";

 $cordovaInAppBrowser.open(finalurl,'_blank');                

 $rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:exit', function(e, event){

 var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title: 'Thank You',
                        template: 'Trancsaction Successfull'
                   });

     });
```

I want alert popup after I will close the CordovaInAppBrowser window